# MVVM Cross REST Service POST and GET

Tags: rest, mvvmcross

I'am new to MVVM and mobile development and looked at N+1 Videos -(http://mvvmcross.blogspot.com/)
 In  particular Book Video makes a rest call to get - Is there any video for POST and GET - I searched but most the of the examples I found where for GET -  Can you point out to REST Service with MVVM for POST and GET with Json Data

Answer (score 2):

James Montemagno recently released a great demo for working with a REST API using MVVMCross. You can find it here:

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MeetupManager

Here's a few steps you can follow when implementing your own:

1. Create your response objects as jsonproperty types(Use json.net)
   EX: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MeetupManager/blob/master/MeetupManager.Portable/Services/Responses/EventsRootObject.cs
2. Create your REST Service via HttpClient (You can find an example here: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MeetupManager/blob/master/MeetupManager.Portable/Services/MeetupService.cs)
3. Use MVVMCross default IoC container to inject your service in the ViewModel's constructor, and use the service as you wish!
   https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MeetupManager/blob/master/MeetupManager.Portable/ViewModels/EventViewModel.cs

By default MVVMCross will register services with the name "Service" at the end such as "APIService.cs" / etc. You can find this in the App.cs file of your Core project.